# Derivative of Vector from the derivative of its norm

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

It is known from previous question that,

$\frac{d}{d x} \left \| \vec{x} \right \| = \frac{\vec{x}}{\left \| \vec{x} \right \|} \cdot \vec{\dot{x}}$

How can I get the vector derivative $\vec{\dot{x}}$ from the norm derivative $\frac{d \left \| \vec{x} \right \| }{d x} $ ?

Comment: Please check if the edition is correct.

Comment: $\vec a\cdot\vec b=\alpha$ has multiple solutions in $\vec b$ because either $||\vec b||$ or $\cos(\widehat{\vec a,\vec b})$ can vary.